# How can i list excel files within a folder with different possible extentions (.xlsx, .xlsb, .xlsm) using python

Tags: python, pandas, file

I want my code to display all the excel files in my folder which may have different extentions.

I tried following but it didnt help

```
os.chdir(path)
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
  if filename.endswith(".xls"):
  print(filename)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  if (".xls" in filename):
     print(filename)
```

or:

```
import os
suffix =('.xls', '.xlsx', '.xlsb')
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
  if (filename.endswith(suffix)):
      print(filename)
```

Comment: getting error  " 'str' object has no attribute 'contains"

Comment: What if the filename is abc.xls.txt ?

Comment: I don't see this happens

Comment: @CtrlZ - but corrected the answer

Answer (score 0):

[pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is perfect for this.

Code:

```
from pathlib import Path

files = [x.name for x in Path.cwd().glob("*.xls*")]
```

Edit:

In the off chance a file is named abc.xls.txt you can add a check.

```
files = [x.name for x in Path.cwd().glob("*.xls*") if x.suffix in [".xlsx", ".xlsm", ".xlsb", ".xls"]]
```

Comment: You need to do some extra work to check the file extension. This code would match, for example, abc.xls.txt

Answer (score 0):

glob patterns could reveal incorrect filenames so you need to do a bit of extra work to ensure that you match filenames that you're really interested in.

```
from pathlib import Path

EXCEL_EXTENSIONS = {
    ".xls",
    ".xlsx",
    ".xlsb",
    ".xlsm"
}
DIR = "." # your directory path goes here

def getSpreadsheets(d):
    for filename in Path(d).iterdir():
        if filename.suffix in EXCEL_EXTENSIONS:
            yield filename

for filename in getSpreadsheets(DIR):
    print(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os

path = "/path/to/your/folder"

os.chdir(path)
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(('.xls', '.xlsx', '.xlsm', '.xlsb')):
        print(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module which finds all the pathnames matching a specified pattern.

Here's the code you may try:

```py
import glob

path = "path/to/folder"
excel_extensions = [".xls", ".xlsx", ".xlsm", ".xlsb"]

excel_files = []
for ext in excel_extensions:
    excel_files.extend(glob.glob(path + f"/*{ext}"))

for file in excel_files:
    print(file)
```